# Spring Boot exception: Could not open ServletContext resource

Tags: java, spring, macos

i am facing a issue with installation of a project. I was mainly working on Windows and everything works fine here (so that the code is 100% working on my machine), recently i switched to the Macbook PRO on the new M1 Pro chip, i managed to install maven, httpd, tomcat and java with brew, and started to configure to run the project, however i get an error:

`java.io.FileNotFoundExceiption: Could not open ServletContext resource [/../conf/application.properties]`

I would like to point that i am using java 8. On my windows machine everything works fine,  what can be the problem? I am first time using Mac OS. Thanks in advice.

Comment: can you mention your IDE?

Comment: Intellij IDEA Ultimate

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling the library... or if not the file mentioned doesn't exist or is corrupt. now check everything(like if any data is corrupt in the library or your files and make sure it exists). If it doesn't work, try including information (like error logs and so on.)in a comment in this answer.

Comment: Tried reinstalling, nothing changed. The file exists, it is not corrupt. The error log i included already, that is the only one which fails and which why does not start application.